# Is converting multiple nested python dictionaries/lists into json going to cause problems if other languages try to decode them?

Tags: python, json, nested, youtube-api

An aim of a research project I am doing using python is that my results are as accessible as possible. As a result, I am converting all my results to JSON so that future researchers who might want to use different languages can access and manipulate my data easily. At present, I am storing the data (YouTube comments data) in Python as multiple nested dictionaries/lists and then writing it to a JSON file:

```
import requests
import json

params = {
    'part': 'snippet,replies',
    'maxResults': 100,
    'videoId': ********,
    'textFormat': 'plainText',
    'key': ***********
    }

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'
    }

comments_data = requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads', params=params, headers=headers)
results = comments_data.json()

comments_list = []

for item in results["items"]:           
    comment = item["snippet"]["topLevelComment"]      
    author = comment['snippet']["authorDisplayName"]     
    text = comment['snippet']["textDisplay"]
    likes = comment['snippet']["likeCount"]
    reply_count = item['snippet']['totalReplyCount']

    comments_list.append({    #appends comment as a dictionary
        "author" : author,
        "text": text,
        "likes": likes,
        "reply_count": reply_count
            })

     if 'replies' in item.keys():     #checks if a comment has any replies
         comments_list[-1].update({"replies":[]})
         for reply in item['replies']["comments"]:
             rep_author = reply['snippet']["authorDisplayName"]     
             rep_text = reply['snippet']["textDisplay"]
             rep_likes = reply['snippet']["likeCount"]

             comments_list[-1]['replies'].append({    #appends replies to latest entry in comments_list (aka its parent)
                 "author" : rep_author,
                 "text": rep_text,
                 "likes": rep_likes
                 })

with open("comments.json, "w", encoding="utf8") as f:
    json.dump(comments_list, f, ensure_ascii=False)
```

As you can see, I am storing information about the comments, in particular the replies, as nested dictionaries.

I only have experience with Python, so I am unsure if other languages would struggle to process this data or not. Can anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 1):

Standard JSON can be decoded without problem if all you're nesting is lists/dicts/quotes. You already did this, but it's worth mentioning that the `str` -> `bytes` encoding should be clear(`"utf-8"` in most cases).

Side note: do fix any typos in the code though :)

Comment: Ah that is cracking news. Could you explain what you mean by the `str` -> `bytes` encoding being clear? Thanks for pointing out the typos!

Comment: When a program in another language reads your bytes json file, it might need to decode the bytes to the string form in that language. So the program needs to be aware of the encoding.